# Separar variable en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

En el siguiente código estoy calculando el tiempo total en horas y minutos de acuerdo a unos valores que ya tengo en mi base de datos, como fecha inicial, hora inicial, fecha final y hora final:

```
        $horaini=$row['fechainicial']." ".$row['horainicial'];
        $horafin=$row['fechafinal']." ".$row['horafinal'];


        $hi = new DateTime($horaini);//fecha inicial
        $hf = new DateTime($horafin);//fecha final

        $intervalo = $hi->diff($hf);
```

Por medio de la variable $intervalo es la que me imprime el valor calculado, directamente cuantas horas y cuantos minutos en total.

Como puedo hacer para separar esos valores de esa variable $intervalo?

Lo que busco es separar los valores para convertirlos directamente en minutos, ya que actualmente el resultado que arroja es algo como esto:

```
<td><?php echo $intervalo->format('%H h %i m'); ?></td>
```

Resultado final: 2h 3m

Cualquier ayuda me puede ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev no entiendo bien lo que dices.

Comment: Hola si, al parecer me equivoqué, prueba con `$horas = $intervalo->h;`, te funciona?

Comment: Perfecto ya lo logre. :) muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque fue resuelta en comentarios

Comment: confirma lo siguiente; quieres convertir esto: 2h 3m a esto 123 minutos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que el resultado del cálculo siempre será una cadena de texto compatible con "2:03" se podría pasar por un script:

```
<?php
$time = '2:03';
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
$total_minutes = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;

echo $total_minutes;
```

el output seria: `123`

si deseas esto en un metodo quedaria asi:

```
<?php

function getMinutes($time)
{
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
    return ($hours * 60) + $minutes;
} 

echo getMinutes('2:03');
```

la salida sería:

`123`